# Grabbing image files from folder and displaying then in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Now I am having problems with some of my code witch seems not to work.

So the problem is that I have a folder (on website) that has 6 images on it. I would like a piece of code that could detect how many images there are in that folder and insert those images in to the website. And when I add more images to the folder, it'll add them automatically to the count and insert them to the website.

Comment: Please post your code which seems not to work.

Comment: Foreword: You cannot scan the directory (under normal conditions) from the client. You have to make an ajax request first to get the directory listing from server.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way to get to files on your server with javascript is trough AJAX requests.

Also, javascript has no way of knowing a new file was uploaded.

So either your uploading page has to fire an event or you must implement a heartbeat kind of script. That means periodically check for new files in folder.

Id strongly recommend using server-side script and AJAX requests.